# How to make responsive logo inside navbar in Boot Strap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a navbar with fixed top. Want the logo to be responsive inside nav bar.
But not able to achieve. Please advise.
Below is the code:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle myButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand logoWidth" href="#"><img src="images/TPS_logo-01.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/btnCart.png" class="btnCart hidden-lg hidden-md"></a>
    <a href="#" class="searchIcon" data-target="searchDiv"><img src="images/btnSearch.png" class="btnCart hidden-lg hidden-md"></a>
</div>
```

Thank you
Monica

Comment: That's really interesting html code....

Comment: where is the code Monica ?

Comment: <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand logoWidth" href="#"><img src="images/TPS_logo-01.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>

Comment: Its hard to tell with the additional class "logoWidth" in navbar-brand. You should post a jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/

Comment: I have a logo inside nav bar, which I want to be responsive. added class img-responsive, but not working. Is there any other approach?

Comment: responsive in which term? width or height? navbars have a fixed height because of padding of inner elements. also add your custom css in question.

Comment: in both terms, width & height

Answer (score 0):

Just give class="img-responsive" in your image class

[www.w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) reference here for bootstrap img-resposive